`mount -t cifs NAS` returns "mount error(2): No such file or directory"
I'm trying to mount a NAS in VS Code server with this command:
mount -t cifs //NAS_ip/dir1 /nas -o rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/config/cred,uid=
(id − u), gid =(id -g),vers=3.0

and I'm getting:

mount error(2): No such file or directory

The directory and NAS are both reachable from my computer.
I tried every possible solution / idea I could find on the internet.
I tried to lower the CIFS version: 1.0, 2.0, 2.0.1, 3.0, 3.1.1 etc.
I tried installing keyutils, with a different bound directory (ex: "nas2", "nas3", etc), with fstab, rebooting the VS Code server and many other tricks I found, but I'm still having this issue.
Any ideas / workarounds to try?

You have posted a picture of a scrollable window, and truncated several important message. Please replace it with a copy and paste of the text, and use the {} formatting tool.

... I don't believe the placement of non-option arguments is mandatory, but it would need to be uid=$(id − u),gid=$(id -g) to get the shell to generate the values via command substitution

Also I forgot to move //NAS_ip/dir1, maybe it's not required, but according to the synopsis it's at least suggested to put device / mountpoint at the end of the command, so maybe try that and see if helps, along with the excess witespace removal: mount -t cifs -o rw,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777,credentials=/config/cred,uid=(id − u),gid=(id -g),vers=3.0 //NAS_ip/dir1 /nas

@Kos i tried with as suggested device/mountpoint at the end of the command and did not work. Any clues on this ? many thanks

okay now i tried on a new docker , and i have the mount error(127): Key has expired but i don't understand why. For context, i have several dockers all supposed to mount to this NAS and since last week only one docker is currently still mounted to NAS. For some reason , the others were unmounted..

I see, so do you need guidance to solve this new issue? If so please edit your question adding this new information (look at how I formatted your previous error message, you can do the same for the new error message)
